# Navigation Controllers in tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

What is the logic or view structure of an app with a tab bar, e.g. 3 different tabs. Each tab having a navigation controller inside the tab viewcontroller tabs?

Where are the navigation controllers created and managed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using NIB files, you can set up the structure of your app right in your main NIB. The structure looks like this:

- UITabViewController

  - UINavigationViewController

    - TabBarItem
    - UIViewController (set to load from Tab 1 View.nib)

      - NavigationItem (for root view of tab 1's nav controller)
  - UINavigationViewController

    - TabBarItem
    - UIViewController (set to load from Tab 2 View.nib)

      - NavigationItem
  - UINavigationViewController

    - TabBarItem
    - UIViewController (set to load from Tab 3 View.nib)

      - NavigationItem

Comment: Thanks. What if a tableview needs to be in one of the navigationItems. So a tableview is in one of the tabs and when a cell is selected the navigation controller for the tab pushes another view, that the user can return to the tableview from using the navigationcontroller?

Comment: You can replace the appropriate UIViewController above with a UITableViewController (or just set your UIViewController's view to be a UITableView, etc.) In your `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method: a) create a view controller you want to navigate to b) do this: `[ self.navigationController pushViewController:<next view controller> animated:YES ]`

Answer (score 3):

This was driving me nuts too so once I got it working I added this:

https://github.com/benbruscella/iPhone-TabBarController-With-NavigationController

Hopefully this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

From the main xib you can set the navigation controllers from there you can set the classes to be uploaded on that navigation controllers......